# Linking error in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-c++-6, linker-errors

I am very new to VC++ and I am running the program on VC++ for the first time. 
I strictly followed the instructions given in Microsoft Programming Visual C++ book and created one project as instructions given.

**About the ex03a.exe:**
            I saw in the path "...\Ex03a\Debug\" and in that no file exists such as ex03a.exe.

I tested my vc++ by executing a simple 'Test.cpp' file. **I was able to run the simple c++ program and I got the output.** And Test.exe is there in '\Test\Debug\Test.exe'

**My Question:**
    How could I get rid off the error. 
[image]

Comment: Using complete words instead of "pgm" and "abt" really improves readability. Also, what's the question?

Comment: Wow, VC 6! A real blast from the past... Seriously, if you're new to Visual C++, why not download the *latest* version for free? [Visual C++ 2010 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/visual-cpp-express).

Comment: @CodyGray bcz In my book programming vc++ , they are teaching with vc++ 6.0

Comment: I get that problem sometimes with the 2010 version. If I try to build again it normally works the second time, don't know what the cause is though.

Comment: @Cody Gray the express version doesn't contain as many libraries as the real thing. You can't create MFC programs with it. And besides, I don't believe that "not using the 2010 edition" is the problem that causes the linker to fail.

Comment: @MrLister: Yes, I wasn't insinuating that it caused the linker error. Thus why I posted it as a comment, not an answer. The point was more general: why waste a lot of time learning a version of Visual Studio that is more than 10 years old, building up skills that don't translate well into newer versions? *Lots* has changed since VC6 and VS2010. They're radically different environments, and the language itself is radically different, too. VC6 is not even close to standards-compliant. Learning that re-entrenches bad habits is not terribly productive learning at all.

Answer (score 3):

Almost always when VS says it isn't able to open a file, it's about opening it for writing.

And almost always this doesn't work because the file is locked.

And almost always this is because the file is an executable that is currently running :-)

This is a specialty of Windows - an exe is not simply loaded, it's locked for all of it's run time. This is probably due to the fact that exe files (actually called portable executables, for whatever reason) contain not only code, but usually also an arbitrary number of resources (like images, etc.), and changing the file on the fly would make the aplication crash hard when it attempts to read one of those resources at run time.

Therefore, I suggest looking for a way to exit / close / terminate the application, so it isn't running any longer, so the file is not locked anymore, so in this case the linker can do its work.

The error message, btw., isn't that intuitive from my point of view - this problem being SO standard, it could at least attempt to tell you anything about this possible source of the problem - afaik, this hasn't been improved until now, probably because most developers have seen this before, found out why it happened, and therefore do not have any more problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

I see that in that screenshot, that you are running multiple versions of VC6.

Now You get that error if you run the newly compiled exe of that program without shutting down the previous compiled exe.

VC tries to overrwrite the exe that is currenty running but encounters that exact error.

Always close the program when you are done.

Comment: I only see one instance of VC 6. The other one is VS 2005 or 2008. But perhaps he has the same project file open and running there, too.